# Is there any tool to check if I used private api before submit to appstore?

Tags: iphone

One of my app was rejected due to using private API.
But Apple did not give me more details.
Is there any tool to detetect and locate the codes where I used private API?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [APIKit](http://ericasadun.com/2009/12/apikit-goes-beta/).